# Find SMBv1 status with Nmap

Tags: nmap, smb

Is there a ready way with nmap's scripting option to find machines with SMB 1 still enabled server side? It'd be a whole lot faster for me to monitor my remediation if it is available.

I'd rather not have to run a complete OpenVAS scan for this one piece of information.

Comment: you can't just run the SMB plugin for OpenVAS?

Comment: @schroeder I'm using Alienvault's OSSIM, and their staff haven't figured out how to make scans only using specific plugins even after several requests over the years.

Comment: Ok, then have you looked at nmap's options? Does it need to be nmap? There are tons of SMB enum scanners that will do this.

Comment: @schroeder ideally I'd like it to be an nmap script but it strictly isn't necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not currently a script to check for this. It would be a trivial change to the existing [`smbv2-enabled`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smbv2-enabled.html) script. Currently, the script has three possible outputs:

- No output: SMB of any version failed.
- "Server supports SMBv2 protocol": Server supports at least SMBv2, possibly also SMBv1.
- "Server doesn't support SMBv2 protocol": Server supports SMBv1 but not SMBv2.

As you can see, there's some ambiguity about whether a SMBv2-enabled host would also support SMBv1. But modifying the script to test each dialect in turn would be pretty simple.

EDIT: This is coming to Nmap soon. https://github.com/nmap/nmap/pull/943

EDIT 2: This is now supported in Nmap 7.60 by the [`smb-protocols`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-protocols.html) script.

Comment: I can't believe someone downvoted one of the core developers of nmap, giving a complete and informative answer to the question.

Comment: This answer is complete & accurate, can someone let us know if this still is the same & no modules released yet other than that of SMB detection etc.??

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick Made a note to implement this and update this answer when done: https://secwiki.org/w/Nmap/Script_Ideas#smb-version

Comment: Nmap 7.60 now includes this feature. https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-protocols.html

Answer (score 2):

There's a script called `smb-vuln-ms08-067` & `smb-vuln-cve2009-3103` contrary to what other answers were. You can use this via `nmap -sU --script smb-vuln-ms08-067.nse -p U:137 <host>` or `nmap --script smb-vuln-ms08-067.nse -p445 <host>`

`nmap --script smb-os-discovery.nse -p445 127.0.0.1` will detect the host & protocol, you would just need to use grep to see if it's still smbv1 supported.

For the Latest SMBv2 Exploit Detection, use: https://github.com/countercept/doublepulsar-c2-traffic-decryptor

**Example Usage**

nmap --script smb-vuln-ms08-067.nse -p445 
nmap -sU --script smb-vuln-ms08-067.nse -p U:137

**Requires**

msrpc
nmap
smb
stdnse
string
table
vulns

Reference: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-vuln-ms08-067.html

Comment: Where in the output of smb-os-discovery is SMB version information shown?
https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-os-discovery.html

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make a semi-functional smbv1-enabled.nse by taking the smbv2-enabled script and removing all the other dialects, leaving only NT LM .12

Remember that SMBv1 is really NT LM .12

Once you do that, you will get one of two results.  If SMBv1 is enabled on the server, you'll get a bogus error that the server does not support smbv2; if SMBv1 is disabled, you won't get any message at all (because the SMB handshake fails).

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap -p139,445 --script smb-protocols IP-target
```