# Information on Eternalblue

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

im trying to gather some information on the Eternalblue exploit which was released by Shadowbroakers back in April. I know that there exists tons of articles related to this exploit, but i haven't really found any article or research papers which goes into depth on the technical side of it. Anyone who knows of any good resources? And did the exploit use a buffer overflow to inject its malicious code?

Thanks

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15373/explain-the-vulnerable-code-used-by-eternalblue-smb-attack

Comment: Here is one article entitled "The ... Hacking Tool That Will Wreak Havoc For Years To Come:  https://www.cyberscoop.com/once-an-nsa-favorite-this-leaked-hacking-tool-will-wreak-havoc-for-years-to-come/

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155769/find-smbv1-status-with-nmap/158896#158896